# Django cannot find module

Tags: python, django

EDIT
So this was a Docker issue, not a Python issue. Thank you everyone for your help!

---

I am working on a Django project. I have several apps within the project and everything has been working fine. I recently added a new app called *files* through **django-admin** and for some reason, Django cannot find this module. This is my project structure

```
core/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
api/
    migrations/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    views.py
files/
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    forms.py
    init_s3.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

The *apps.py* for the *files* module reads:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class FilesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'files'
```

Which is almost word-for-word how the AppConfig for the *api* module is written:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
```

I have the *api* and *files* app installed in the **INSTALLED_APPS** setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...other apps...

    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'files.apps.FilesConfig'
]
```

Django has no problems locating the *api* app, but cannot find the *files* app. When I run the server, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'files'
```

What's going on here? What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: 1. Please check which python you are using. 2. Please check the same setting file is being used for running the server or not which you have edited. Try simply stopping the server and start again.

Comment: 1. 3.7.7
2. How do I verify the setting file is being used?Also,  I've tried restarting the server, no dice.

Comment: try using `python3 manage.py runserver` should work, but before this needs to ensure python 3 is installed.

Comment: I'm actually deploying the WSGI application on a gunicorn server, if that changes any considerations. When I run it locally with manage.py, I get the same error.

Comment: The #1 in my comment was an answer to your #1. I'm on 3.7.7. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: adding `files` instead of `files.apps.FilesConfig` in settings file should work then. When you make this change is server restarting automatically?

Comment: Tried that too. I get the same error. Do you want me to change the setting while the server is running?

Comment: yes, to ensure you are editing same setting file where you made changes, so when you edit setting file, server will auto restart.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the app name to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...other apps...

'files'
]
```

Comment: Same deal. 
```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'files'

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your project's urls.py file? it should read:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path('files/', include('files.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Yep, I have included the files.url in the urlpatterns in the project's root urlconf.

Comment: Do you have a repo somewhere?

Comment: I do: https://github.com/GSA/sinwebapp/tree/s3/sinwebapp